# Scripts called within html files end up referring to localhost address instead of local folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wrote a simple web server using express to show an HTML page.

```
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, ()=> console.log('Listening on port 3000'))
```

Within the html, I am calling up a local js file as follows:

```
<script src="./src/file.js"><script>
```

When the page is loaded, the JS files are not loaded throwing the error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/src/file.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Of course, this address does not exist, hence its not being loaded.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the page is served from `localhost:3000` then `./` will be that domain.  I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Use `<script src="/file.js"><script>` instead. In your HTML, you need to use URL paths, not file system paths (that's because the browser is requesting the script from the server, so it's supposed to be a valid URL that'll work from "outside" the server; the issue you're describing in your question title is the only way this is going to work; the browser doesn't have direct access to the server's hard drive)

Comment: I've tried "/file.js" instead of "./file.js" as well, but I experience the same problem.

Comment: Based on the `express.static` line, if you put `http://localhost:3000/file.js` in your browser's address bar and press enter, you should see the script.

Comment: It works now! The /src was unnecessary. If you put that down as an answer I can accept it and upvote you. Thanks!